# Apply a theme to a custom field

Tags: theming, hooks

I have a custom field with formatter which is currently outputting via field.html.twig

I've modified the theme function to

```
function mymodule_theme()
{
    return [
        'field__field_family_and_education' => ['base_hook' => 'field'],
    ];
}
```

and the twig debug indicates it's now using this template, however, despite copying the field.html.twig to field--field-family-and-education.html.twig the variables are not being passed to the template. I want the template to reside in the module, not in the main theme so this is being done within the module that defines the field & formatter.

I'm guessing I've missed an obvious step, any ideas?

Comment: "the variables are not being passed to the template" <- what does this mean?

Comment: Within the template the variables are empty, for example
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}


Gives nothing, plain text within the template (as expected) gets output. So the field content is not getting to the my template, but does get to the default one when.

Currently the template is a direct copy of the default field template.

Comment: If I copy the new template into the core theme folder  (just for testing purposes) the variables populate OK so I guess I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: Digging further, with the twig dump(), the "items", field_name/type, label variables are not populated when my template is loaded, all other variables appear to be OK. Is there something different to overriding a template that is within a module to overriding one within a theme?

Comment: I think you need to implement hook_theme_suggestions_alter().